# How to create dummy ExecutionContext for CanActivate function for unit testing?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have authGuard service with canActivate function ```

```
canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise | Observable
```

const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
const { req } = ctx.getContext();    ```
For testing this function with some header value and all, I need to pass ExecutionContext.
So How to create dummy ExecutionContext for test this function?
This is the interface of ExecutionContext.

````
export interface ExecutionContext extends ArgumentsHost {
    /**
     * Returns the *type* of the controller class which the current handler belongs to.
     */
    getClass<T = any>(): Type<T>;
    /**
     * Returns a reference to the handler (method) that will be invoked next in the
     * request pipeline.
     */
    getHandler(): Function;
}


export interface ArgumentsHost {
    /**
     * Returns the array of arguments being passed to the handler.
     */
    getArgs<T extends Array<any> = any[]>(): T;
    /**
     * Returns a particular argument by index.
     * @param index index of argument to retrieve
     */
    getArgByIndex<T = any>(index: number): T;
    /**
     * Switch context to RPC.
     * @returns interface with methods to retrieve RPC arguments
     */
    switchToRpc(): RpcArgumentsHost;
    /**
     * Switch context to HTTP.
     * @returns interface with methods to retrieve HTTP arguments
     */
    switchToHttp(): HttpArgumentsHost;
    /**
     * Switch context to WebSockets.
     * @returns interface with methods to retrieve WebSockets arguments
     */
    switchToWs(): WsArgumentsHost;
    /**
     * Returns the current execution context type (string)
     */
    getType<TContext extends string = ContextType>(): TContext;

}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two immediate ways I know of you can do this. One is to provide a minimum object that has the base properties you need. Something possibly like this:

```js
const mockContext = {
  switchToHttp: () => ({
    getRequest: () => ({
      headers: {},
      body: {},
      youGetTheIdea: {}
    }),
    getResponse: () => similarResMock,
  })
}
```

However, as you're making use of the `GqlExecutionContext` you'll need to assign the return values to the `getArgs` method that `ExecutionContext` has instead of the `switchTo...` methods. That would look like this:

```js
const mockContext = {
  getType: () => 'graphql',
  getArgs: () => [{}, {}, gqlContextObject, gqlInfo]
}
```

With both of these, unless you want to go and mock out each method, you'll need to use `as any`.

The other option you have is to use a mock object creator. If you're using `jest` you can use `@golevelup/ts-jest`'s `createMock` function, which can be made of use like this:

```js
const mockContext = createMock<ExecutionContext>({
  getType: () => 'graphql',
  getArgs: () => [{}, {}, contextMock, infoMock]
})
```

And this will return a fully valid `ExecutionContext` that you can pass without using `as any` or any other type coercion methods.

[I've got an example you can see here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma/blob/main/packages/platform-graphql/test/graphql-interceptor.service.spec.ts#L7)